# Vuex mapGetters can't find store

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-native

I'm building a mobile native app in vue-native but I've got a problem. I want to retrieve the state of something in my store but it can't seem to find the store.
This is my code:

```
import {mapGetters, mapActions} from 'vuex'
import Store from '../../store/Index'

computed: {
        ...mapGetters('dashboard', ['recent'])
    },
```

This is what my store looks like:
[image]

My Index.js in my dashboard folder:

```
import actions from './Actions'
import getters from './Getters'
import mutations from './Mutations'

export default function () {
    return {
        namespaced: true,
        state: {
            recent: {
                data: [],
            },
            visited: {
                data: [],
                pagination: null
            },
            own: {
                data: [],
                pagination: null
            }
        },
        actions,
        getters,
        mutations
    }
}
```

And my Index.js in my modules folder:

```
import Vue from "vue-native-core";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import user from './modules/user/Index'
import dashboard from './modules/dashboard/Index'
import communities from'./modules/communities/Index'
import settings from './modules/settings/Index'
import search from './modules/search/Index'

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        user: user(),
        dashboard: dashboard(),
        communities: communities(),
        settings: settings(),
        search: search(),
    },
});
export default store;
```

I keep getting this error;

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'store._modulesNamespaceMap')
```

Does anyone have any idea? I think I'm not referencing the 'recent' in my computed the right way.

Comment: Could you please try the other `mapGetters` syntaxe :  `...mapGetters({
  recent: 'dashboard/recent',
})`

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.$store.getters')

Comment: Thanks, I think that you forget to inject your store in the Vue instance. Could you please edit the question with the file where you create the initial Vue instance ? It must be a `new Vue(...)` binded to a DOM element.
I will provide you the answer when it will be done.